# VPS displaying funny characters instead of special characters

Tags: xen, ansi

Pretty sure it doesn't matter but I've had about a dozen OpenVz vps' and never seen this until I bought a Xen server for the first time.

Special characters like « get all funky and look like this: ï¿½

What can be done to so the characters display properly? Using Debian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you connecting to the VPS, via PuTTY for example? If yes, set the encoding to UTF-8 in the settings ("Translations").

If you're connecting from a client via ssh command directly, please show us the output of `echo $LANG` (both on the client and the server).

Comment: `Rx:~# echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8` And I am using putty, but can't seem to find settings -> translations

Comment: when I do echo $LANG on my openVZ vps' I get no output

Comment: Sorry - the PuTTY setting is in Window -> Translation. If your VPS doesn't show anything in $LANG you need to configure the locale via `dkpkg-reconfigure locales`.

Comment: `Rx:/etc/default# more locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
`